# using global site tag (ga gtag) code for custom tags

Tags: google-analytics, gtag.js

Can this one gtag code from GA  be used for own tags, or does tag manager need another tag on each page?

```
<!-- Global site tag (gtag.js) - Google Analytics -->
<script async src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=xxxx"></script>
<script>
  window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
  function gtag(){dataLayer.push(arguments);}
  gtag('js', new Date());

  gtag('config', xxx');
</script>
```

Comment: The question is not clear.

Answer (score 0):

As per Google Analytics documentation:

> To install the global site tag, copy the following code and paste it immediately after the  tag on every page of your site. Replace GA_MEASUREMENT_ID with the ID of the Google Analytics property to which you want to send data. **You need only one global snippet per page.**

https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gtagjs#install_the_global_site_tag